# MarkLogic "Could not find trigger module" error when update triggered in Amps

Tags: paypal, xquery, marklogic, paypal-rest-sdk

Getting an `XDMP-TRIGGERMODULE: Could not find trigger module:` error when updating a document from an Amps module.

Do triggers have issues running from amps?

Setup is for PayPal payment verification, using webhooks. The PayPal API sends an HTTP callback to an endpoint on the MarkLogic server, notifying the server of payment completion. The endpoint code then processes the message, and sends relevant data to an amps module for execution. The idea is the webhook needs to hit a public endpoint, so it will be using the default public user in terms of execution permissions. The amp is used so the code can have the appropriate permissions to update the document, noting that the payment has been received.

A separate (unrelated) trigger is set up to run on any modification of the same aforementioned document, for the purposes of a separate unrelated process. This trigger runs perfectly fine when the document is modified in all other ways, as intended for its intended purpose, but for some reason when the amp module modifies the document, the `XDMP-TRIGGERMODULE` error is triggered instead, causing the whole transaction to fail, and preventing the amp code from ever executing (and therefore preventing the payment completion from being recorded).

I'm wondering if there is some sort of issue with the trigger being triggered by an update done in an amp module? If so, how can I avoid this problem occurring? The trigger code isn't even needed in this particular case, but it is set up to run on all modifications to this specific type of document, and I'm not sure if there's a way to prevent that in unique cases.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: You may be relying on trigger permissions assigned to the amp role, rather than to a role inherited by the user directly. Amp roles are very likely not carried over to the trigger..

Answer (score 0):

If your organization has support from MarkLogic, I would recommend you go via them.

Otherwise, more data is required to help you. Perhaps the trigger code and the amped module code that invokes it and how the amp is setup and information about the user/role calling the module would be useful.